# Adding a datasource to Codesmith

Tags: codesmith

I am trying to add a DataSource to Codesmith  7.1.0 rev 15317
This is a new install on a Windows 10 box.

I keep getting the error

```
Test Failed. Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

I have done this many times on my old win8 box.

The provider I am using is SqlSchemaProvider (SQL Server)
This is the connection string

```
Data Source=localhost;InIitial Catalog=gregsData;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=catdog;
```

I have tried using the string builder, copying from my app where I know it is working, adding and deleting various parts.

I have an issue open w/ CodeSmithTools, but not making a lot of progress.

Is anyone using CodeSmith w/ windows 10? It has to work right? This cant be a bug.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: its happening again. funny... i find my own post on SO

Comment: What happens if you try a different connection string format? Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

Comment: @Blake, Ill try that at next opportunity. Per our support session , this error has retreated to 'cant reproduce' status.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what resolved this. maybe a reboot? maybe some odd update. 
I came in one monday and it started working.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Can you mark one of these as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can not find an answer anywhere. 
uninstalled and reinstalled...again. No luck.

I finally had the ODBC idea. I created an ODBC datasource, then used that using the ADOXSchemaProvider.
This works.

Not great, but this beats coding by hand, and for now, it beats converting all my templates to something else.

here is a sample ODBC connection string if you need to go this route. 
DSN=myDsn;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=mypwd;

Comment: this turned out not to work. although you can select a table, the template will not generate. it fails with an error saying it cant find one of the fields.